# Converting a coordinate from one space to another

Tags: java, math, coordinate

I seem to be having a bit of a math fail here... I need to convert an (x,y) point from one coordinate space to another - not in the sense of polar to cartesian or anything of the sort... just from one bound to another. i.e., for a particular (x,y) that falls in the rectangle with lower left (-100, -100) and upper right (100,100), I need to find out where that point would be in a rectangle with lower left (0,0) and upper right (500, 500).

I feel like this is just simple math but I'm having a heck of a time getting it right...

It is for a little computer graphics program written in java. Essentially there is a clip window that changes, and that clip window needs to fill the whole view window. Initial values for clip and view are given by the above rectangles, in that order. However, the clip could change to, for example, a rectangle with lower left (-80, -65) and upper right (75, 65). I would then need to convert a point that falls within that rectangle to a point that falls within the view window (lower left (0,0), upper right (500, 500))

Here is what I have for it right now:

```
public int normalizeX(float x) {
    float clipWidth = clipRight - clipLeft;
    int viewWidth = viewRight - viewLeft;
    x += 100; //Get x into range [0, 200] instead of [-100, 100]
    //First convert x to value within clip width, then "scale" to viewport width
    return (int)(((clipWidth*x)/200) * (viewWidth/clipWidth));
}

public int normalizeY(float y) {
    float clipHeight = clipTop - clipBottom;
    int viewHeight = viewTop - viewBottom;
    y += 100; //Get y into range [0, 200] instead of [-100, 100]
    //First convert y to value within clip height, then "scale" to viewport height
    return (int)(((clipHeight*y)/200) * (viewHeight/clipHeight));
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Where are the hardcoded `[0, 200]` and `[-100, 100]` coming from?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder Jean. James, those values came from the fact that all shapes, regardless or clip or view window, were defined in the range (-100, -100), (100, 100).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your old bounds are `xLoOld` and `xHiOld` (-80 and 75, respectively, in your example) and your new bounds are `xLoNew` and `xHiNew` (0 and 500, respectively, in your example), then you can normalize your `xOld` to your new coordinate system like this:

```
xNew = (xOld-xLoOld) / (xHiOld-xLoOld) * (xHiNew-xLoNew) + xLoNew
```

Same thing for y.

Comment: Shouldn't the last bit there be `+ xLoNew`?

Comment: ahh, yes i was about to mention that but someone beat me to it :-p thanks!

Comment: {xLoOld} are you serious with those variable names?? :)

Comment: Dead serious. But by all means, please do enlighten us with your seriousness-exuding variable names, pedant! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this may help you.

```
    public static float scale(
           float x,
           float old_min, float old_max,
           float new_min, float new_max)
    {
        float old_range = old_max - old_min;
        float new_range = new_max - new_min;
        return new_min + (x - old_min) * new_range / old_range;
    }
```

You will need to scale your coordinates in both dimensions. I've left out other computations such as casting to int, etc.

I also recommend creating suitable types such as `Region` or `Rectangle` to simplify your code by, at least, reducing the number of arguments to this function.

Comment: Thanks! and the region rectangle thing isn't an issue. the old and new bounds are maintained in global variables that are changed with setter methods. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Simple as hell: you want a transformation which maps -100 to 0 and 100 to 500. Or put blindly, which maps the range [-100, 100] to the range [0, 500] :

```
[-100, 100] ----> [0, 500]
```

First step is to convert the range [-100, 100] to [0, 200]:

```
x ----> x + 100
```

Next step is to convert the range [0, 200] to [0, 500]

```
x ----> x * 500 / 200 = 2.5 * x
```

*In fine*, your transformation reads

```
x ----> 2.5 * (x + 100)
```

and likewise for y:

```
y ----> 2.5 * (y + 100).
```

Hope this makes it clear, and that you will be able to reuse the logic in more complex cases.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Not sure why I was struggling so much. Makes me embarrassed as a math minor :-X guess i was just having a brain fart

Comment: @user1028885: You're welcome. I have a math degree, I do math all day long at work and I *do* need paper and pencil to do these things. It is easy to mess things up.

Comment: Typical mathematicians! You guys are terrible with numbers. Yours truly, a physicist.  (PS: You know it's true! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The slick and general way to do this is with an affine transform.
You'll have a 2 x 2 matrix (call it A) that characterizes the "stretchiness" of the original field to the second field, and a 2 x 1 matrix (call it b) characterizing the offset.

Then, with x as your (2 x 1) input and y as your (2 x 1) output, it's just y = Ax + b.

The technique also lets you do a lot more (like rotations) but those probably aren't important for your application.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation